# Do compilers optimize out parameters that aren't used?

Tags: c++, optimization

Suppose I have a very simple inline function:

```
void Trace(int i)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

Now I call this function with the parameter generated by another function that takes a long time:

```
Trace(SlowFunc());
```

Will a reasonable compiler optimize out the call to `SlowFunc()` in release mode? Specifically will MSVC do it?

Comment: if the compiler cannot proove that `SlowFunc()` has no sideeffects it is not allowed to optimize it away

Comment: I would think it depends on what `SlowFunc()` does.  If it has side effects it probably can't optimize away its call.

Comment: @user463035818 extremely good point, I should have thought of that.

Comment: If `SlowFunc` is only in the business of collecting information to be printed for debug porpoises (e.g. memory usage) there's a good chance that it doesn't have side effects. However, that kind of call will likely be too convoluted for the compiler to make an easy decision. I'd play safe and assume it would give up.

Comment: there are similar things the get 'optimized' out. It is very common to see in beginner code `assert(SlowFunc())`, this works fine in DEBUG mode but in production assert is a no-op. This is not a compiler optimization though, its due to the definition of assert

Comment: Yes, [MSVC does it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/obgcqG) but the compiler must be able to prove that it has no side effects.

Comment: @RaymondChen +1million for actually posting proof; too many responses to questions like this boil down to 'yes, in theory' without ever looking at practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The optimization would only be allowed if SlowFunc() is proven to have no side effects - but in practice, long-running functions are usually ridden with side-effects (unless it is some sort of heavy computational math, but then the optimizer might give up on it). If SlowFunc() is proven to have no side effects, this call can be optimized out.

But I would not rely on it. Instead, use a logging solution which only calculates the argument when DEBUG is enabled. There are a couple of options, let me know if you'd like some pointers.

Comment: Thanks for being the first person brave enough to leave an answer instead of a comment. No need for additional help, I was already finished writing a macro when I wondered if it was absolutely necessary.